# boost::shared_ptr in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, boost, objective-c++

This is a better understanding of a question I had earlier.

I have the following Objective-C++ object

```
@interface OCPP
{
    MyCppobj * cppobj; 
}
@end

@implementation OCPP

-(OCPP *) init
 {
   cppobj = new MyCppobj;
 }
 @end
```

Then I create a completely differently obj which needs to use cppobj in a boost::shared_ptr (I have no choice in this matter, it's part of a huge library which I cannot change)

```
@interface NOBJ
-(void) use_cppobj_as_shared_ptr
{
    //get an OCPP obj called occ from somewhere..
    //troubling line here
}
@end
```

I have tried the following and that failed: I tried synthesising cppobj. Then I created a shared_ptr in "troubling line" in the following way:

```
MyCppobj * cpp = [occ cppobj];
bsp = boost::shared_ptr<MyCppobj>(cpp);
```

It works fine first time around. Then I destroy the NOBJ and recreate it. When I for cppobj it's gone. Presumably shared_ptr decided it's no longer needed and did away with it.

So I need help. How can I keep cppobj alive?

Is there a way to destroy bsp (or it's reference to cppobj) without destroying cppobj?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the init method.
Usually you return 'self' and the return type is 'id'.
I guess this also holds for ObjC++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` supports custom deallocators. What you can do, is, do nothing.

```
void no_destroy(MyCppObj*)
{}

bsp = boost::shared_ptr<MyCppObj>(cpp, &no_destroy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `boost::shared_ptr<MyCppObj> cppobj;` in `OCPP` instead of `MyCppobj * cppobj;` to store the instance of MyCppObj?

Comment: Then how do I pass this shared_ptr? I tried that and for some reason it failed.

Comment: Add a method like this: "- (boost::shared_ptr<MyCppobj>) getCppobj {return cppobj;}" to the OCPP class and access the member cppobj through this method.
Now the pointer belongs to the instance of OCPP and will only get deleted when this instance is deallocated.